# Place a document length and width div behind all other content

Tags: html, css, layout, position, css-position

I have [this](http://jsbin.com/atoDunImI/2/edit) layout @ http://jsbin.com/atoDunImI/2/edit. The `#some_other_pos_abs_thing` is supposed to contain the real page contents. The `#whole_page_box` is supposed to go in the background behind all other content. I can do that with `position:absolute` and `z-index`. The problem is, I need the `#whole_page_box` to take the width and height of the whole page and not of the screen. This is because this div will contain an SVG element and JS will be used to draw stuff onto it based on the user's interactions with the contents of `#some_other_pos_abs_thing`. As you can see in the example:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

doesn't accomplish what I want. What will? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: can u add screenshot showing issue...?

Comment: You can see it in action @ http://jsbin.com/atoDunImI/2/edit.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set any value for the height of the document, so 100% defaults to the window size.

First off, you need to set an absolute value for the height and width of `body`, e.g.

```
body { height: 2000px; width: 3000px }
```

Then, you can get rid of most of the styling you did on `#whole_page_box`, and add a z-index to it:

```
#whole_page_box {
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .1);
}
```

Of course, since the main content div is offset 100px vertically, you'll need to tack on 100px to the `body` height. The same goes for the `body` width.

If you're loading content from a database, you can use jQuery (or plain JS) to get the document width and height then change the height of `body`, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function({
    var docH = $(document).width();
    var docW = $(document).height();
    $('body').css('width', docW).css('height', docH);
});
```

Comment: Ok. But the content is supposed to be coming from a DB. I wouldn't know the height and width of the content. I only put in those `height` and `width` values to make the scroll bars appears for all screen sizes.

Comment: I updated my answer for that; use jQuery to get the height/width of the document then set it as the body height/width.

Comment: I'm looking for a pure CSS-based solution for this. I'd prefer not to clutter the page with JS that does layout-related stuff, if at all possible.